# Box or Google Drive as storage for nodejs webapp

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, box

I'm developing a webapp in nodejs that require the upload of some media and
I'm deciding if using Google Drive or Box as storage for static media of my app.

Both solutions use oauth2 for authentication, but I can't understand how to connect my node app to a single account (where the storage must be). The problem is that I can't find in their documentation an example that fit my problem.

What I have to do to implements this?
If it's not possible what are good cloud storage alternatives that offers free space? I don't want to pay for a service before of a production environment

Comment: For Drive, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784575/google-drive-help-required-access-to-own-drive-account/28789719#28789719

Comment: Why duplicate? I'm not asking only for google drive authentication

Comment: It's a duplicate because you ask how to connect your node app to a single account and the referenced SO question tells you how to do that. Your question should be broken down into smaller, specific questions. As it stands you're asking for generic advice and that is not the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Unless each user is going to be uploading content to their own Google Drive or Box (which it doesn't appear to be in this case). Both of those options aren't really the right solution to your problem.

If you're simply doing static assets that don't frequently change, just keep them as assets in your project. This would be the right approach for things like logos.

Otherwise you should look into either Amazon Web Service or Google Cloud Services. Both are pretty inexpensive for small amounts of storage. Not sure about Google Cloud, but AWS gives you a small amount of storage for free for the first year. This would be a better solution if you have some web interface that requires you to upload an image, for say a blog.

It all just depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: "Unless each user is going to be uploading content to their own Google Drive or Box Both of those options aren't really the right solution to your problem" - Why not?

Comment: They weren't built to be serving web page assets and files like AWS and Google Cloud Services were. They're better used for backing up personal/enterprise data. So something like 1password backing up your passwords to your personal dropbox, is a better solution than backing it up to the 1Password AWS. It's about who it's servicing in the end.

Comment: I think it depends what the OP is actually asking for. If he intends to serve the assets directly to the browser, I agree. But the question doesn't say that. It says "store" not "serve", and "connect my node app to Drive" suggesting that they will be served from his nodejs webapp, but stored outside the app in Drive. In that case, Drive is a perfectly good solution.